# Add a field error in Django Rest Framework validate method?

Tags: python, django

In Django Rest Framework (and Django), traditionally we check fields in `validate_<field>` method, and make more global checks in `validate` method.

However, look at this code snippet:

```
def validate(self, data):
    # ....
    try:
        customer.activate(data['signup_code'], data['raw_password'])
    except BadCodeProvided:
        raise ValidationError(MSG_WRONG_ACTIVATION_CODE)
    except SomeOtherException:
        raise ValidationError(SOME_OTHER_MESSAGE)
```

Here, I'm forced to use `validate`method because I'm using 2 fields for my validation (signup_code and raw_password).
However, if an error occurs in a BadCodeProvided Exception, I know it's related to the signup_code field (and not the raw_password one) because of the exception raised here.

In the snippet code above, thiw will create a "non_field_error".
Question: is there a way in DRF to raise the same error but related to the "signup_code" field? (like it would be done in a `validate_signup_code` method).

Thanks

Answer (score 25):

you can use `serializers.ValidationError` in serializer :

```
raise serializers.ValidationError({"myField": "custom message error 1",
                               "myField2": "custom message error 1"})
```

doc here [Validator DRF](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#validation)